# PHP mailer not showing text-danger alerts, also goes to a blank page when submitted

Tags: php, html, forms, modal-dialog, mailer

The PHP contact form modal on my site is sending email, but it isn't displaying error messages if fields are left blank or if the wrong number is put in when verifying whether someone is human or not. Also, after you click submit, it goes to a blank page.

Here's my HTML file:

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="contactModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contactModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Fill everything out below!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
              <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="mailer.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message">
                      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST[ 'message']);?>
                    </textarea>
                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer">
                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errHuman</p>";?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <?php echo $result; ?>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- End of Modal body -->
    </div>
    <!-- End of Modal content -->
  </div>
  <!-- End of Modal dialog -->
</div>
<!-- End of Modal -->
```

And here's my PHP file:

```html
<?php
 if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $human = intval($_POST['human']);
  $from = 'Contact Form'; 
  $to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; 
  $subject = 'Message from porfolio site ';
  
  $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
 
  // Check if name has been entered
  if (!$_POST['name']) {
   $errName = 'Please enter your name';
  }
  
  // Check if email has been entered and is valid
  if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
  }
  
  //Check if message has been entered
  if (!$_POST['message']) {
   $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
  }
  //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
  if ($human !== 5) {
   $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
  }
 
// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
 if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
  $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
 } else {
  $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
 }
}
 }
?>
```

Do y'all know what could be going on here?

Comment: you are not submitting this via AJAX so basically you are sending all of your information to your mailer.php page which doesn't output anything, you could toss `echo $result;` at the end of that file if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fields are probably empty strings, which would pass the `(!$_POST['field'])` test. Instead, use `if(!empty($_POST['field']))`. This makes sure the field exists, is not 0, null, or an empty string.

For instance:

```
if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $errName = 'Please enter your name';
}
```

Comment: Hm, doing this actually made the mailer stop working altogether, so I reverted back to the previous file.